# Warning 'NaN or Inf found in input tensor. ' while training, and these are logs of calling torch.autograd.detect_anomaly. I don't understand them

Tags: pytorch

The error happens at random iteration from hundreds to thousands without shuffling input data. Input data are ok because they are used in another model normally. The 'NaN or Inf found in input tensor. ' warning occurs in the model that I modified from a working well model. It just suddenly happens that all losses become NaN before an epoch finishes. I suspect that something is wrong in the layers of the model, but I don't know how to find it and fix it.

```
def forward(self, x):
    # return self.model(x)
    x1_1 = self.cov1_1(x)
    x1_2 = self.cov1_2(x1_1)
    x1_3 = self.cov1_3(x1_2)
    x1_out = x1_1 + x1_3

    x2_1 = self.cov2_1(x1_out)
    x2_2 = self.cov2_2(x2_1)
    x2_3 = self.cov2_3(x2_2)
    x2_out = x2_1 + x2_3

    x3_1 = self.cov3_1(x2_out)
    x3_2 = self.cov3_2(x3_1)
    x3_3 = self.cov3_3(x3_2)
    x3_out = x3_1 + x3_3

    x4_1 = self.cov4_1(x3_out)
    x4_2 = self.cov4_2(x4_1)
    x4_3 = self.cov4_3(x4_2)
    x4_out = x4_1 + x4_3

    return {
        'x1_out': x1_out,
        'x2_out': x2_out,
        'x3_out': x3_out,
        'x4_out': x4_out,
    }



      5%|▌         | 1498/27513 [1:12:34<20:48:35,  2.88s/it]:
  5%|▌         | 1499/27513 [1:12:37<20:39:44,  2.86s/it]:
  5%|▌         | 1500/27513 [1:12:40<20:42:22,  2.87s/it]:
[W ..\torch\csrc\autograd\python_anomaly_mode.cpp:104] Warning: Error detected in AddBackward0. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\train.py", line 236, in <module>
    dices = trainer.gen_update(images, labels, config, missModality)
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\trainer.py", line 357, in gen_update
    c, s_flair_prime, s_t1_prime, s_t1ce_prime, s_t2_prime = self.gen_uni.encode(x_miss_1_modality, missModality=missModality)
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\networks.py", line 246, in encode
    contentsDic = self.enc_content(images)
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\networks.py", line 551, in forward
    x3_1 = self.cov3_1(x2_out)
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\networks.py", line 894, in forward
    x = self.conv(self.pad(x))
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 446, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 442, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
 (function _print_stack)
  5%|▌         | 1500/27513 [1:12:43<21:01:16,  2.91s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\train.py", line 236, in <module>
    dices = trainer.gen_update(images, labels, config, missModality)
  File "D:\codes\220124_brainTumor\tmi_220521\MUNIT_tmi_seg _unifiedCC_lms220801\trainer.py", line 488, in gen_update
    self.loss_gen_total.backward()
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py", line 307, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\MLAI\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 154, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: Function 'AddBackward0' returned nan values in its 1th output.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: really need some help!!

Comment: So do we. There's no detail provided on the `cov` functions, on the loss function implementation, or on the data.